# Kion signifas "Mi traktas min..."?

Tags: verbs, word-meaning

Mi legis el la profilo de flua esperantisto: *Mi **traktas min** profesia esperantisto, ĉar...*

Nu, mi neniam vidis la verbon *trakti* uzita por *min* kaj pensis, ĉu gramatike tio estas ĝusta kaj signifas *Mi konsideras min kiel profesian instruiston* aŭ ĉu ĝi estas eraro?

Mi rimarkis ankaŭ, ke la frazo ne enhavas la vorton *kiel*. Ĉu tio taŭgas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nu, la frazo surprizas ankaŭ min, sed ni pripensu momente.

Unue, estas klare ke oni ja sufiĉe ofte uzas la verbon “trakti” kun “min”.

- Hieraŭ nokte ili traktis min kun hontinda malŝato.
- vi traktis min kiel favan publikulinon

Tio kion ni malpli ofte vidas estas “trakti sin.”

- [Malbonaj viroj] mistraktas sin kaj aliajn per vortoj kaj agoj.

Kion tio povas signifii? Ni konsideru la duan difinon en PIV: *Tia- aŭ ali-maniere agi, konduti kontraŭ iu aŭ io.*

Tiu difino havas sencon en la ekzemploj supre, sed ŝajne malpli en la frazo "Mi traktas min profesia esperantisto“. Rimarku ankaŭ ke oni traktas iun kiel ion. Malpli oftas ekzemploj sen ”kiel“ aŭ sen adverbo:

- Tamen se iu traktas Esperanton superflua lukso

(Ne estas klare al mi ĉu la ĉi-supra ekzemplo havas sencon sen "kiel +n".)

Mi ne sukcesis trovi la originalan kuntekston, sed mi emas supozi ke la skribinto volis diri ke li **taksas** sin profesia Esperantisto. ”Trakti sin kiel profesian Esperantiston“ ja havas sencon, sed strangan. (Mi agas al mi kaj kondutas kontraŭ mi kvazaŭ mi estas profesia Esperantisto.) Ankaŭ eblas ke temas pri nacilingva influo. Ekzemple IT:*trattarsi*. "Mi vivas kiel profesia esperantisto."
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trattarsi

Comment: Dankon pro la atentigo. Mi korekgis gxin. Versxajne mi mislernis la vorton pro la ludo "Difin-defio."

Comment: Dankon. Nur unu demandon. 'Taksi iun' ĉiam havas pozitivan sencon, ĉu ne?

Comment: Laŭ mi, ĝi estas neŭtrala.